# Requirements for a game

Tags: iphone

I'm writing an iPhone game and I am trying to write some requirements documents.  I have never written requirements before so I got the book Software Requirements.  I have not finished it yet, but I forsee some issues, as this book is targeted towards a business.  My main question is I am the only person involved with this game and I feel the main purpose of the requirements document should be to nail out as many conceptual ideas of how the game works as I can before I am deep into design or construction.  Does anyone have suggestions on how I should lay this out, should I still try to mimic the template provided in the book where it makes sense, or since I am both the sole developer and product owner, should I just stick to game concepts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right that traditional SRS documents don't really fit games documentation all that well. Games instead have a general Game Design Document. It's usually created before any work on the game begins, and it's often edited as the development process goes to keep straight the intended end-result and specifics of the game.

While business software requirements documents are like contracts between a client and developer on what to produce, game design docs are more often specifications from the designer to the artists and programmers on what exactly they need to develop.

There is no specific layout to use. But you should consider who you're writing the document for. Is it for a class, for yourself, for peers after the project is done? The level of detail and the kind of things you include will be different depending on your audience. The format itself is very flexible, as long as it's coherent.

Brenda Brathwaite has a good [blog entry](http://bbrathwaite.wordpress.com/2008/11/30/creating-a-game-design-document/) on this subject which you might find helpful.
There is a semi-recent [article](http://blog.slickedit.com/2007/05/how-to-write-an-effective-design-document/) from gamedev.net on the subject as well.

Comment: It is for myself, but also I plan to open source everything once its on the app store, so then it will be for anyone.  Thanks for the links, very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

[Poor Jacob, you just read a book on the topic, and, collectively, the SO community writes another one for you, along with extra links, and probably with diverging views ;-) ]

Although I'm not familiar with the book you mention in the question, I think that the following suggestion may help you both take seriously, but also relax a bit, about the all too important question of requirements.

Being a "team of one", **it is particularly important, and somewhat paradoxical, that you go through the effort of formalizing the requirements**.  However, rather than putting too much emphasis on the *form*, you may find an [**Agile**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agile_development) approach to developement (and hence to requirements gathering) more appropriate.  With regards to requirements, one of the main advantages of this approach, is flexibility, i.e. the understanding that while they should be formalized (with limited time/effort), requirements should be allowed to change (within limits) as part of an iterative process towards production of the target product.

In very broad terms, this generally go as follows:

- write "[**user stories**](http://www.mountaingoatsoftware.com/articles/27-advantages-of-user-stories-for-requirements)", these are individual "cards" (yes, physical cards, say 4 inches by 5 inches, are good, for you can then move then around, sort them etc.)
- each story tells **a particular feature** of the application, here the game, **from the end-user's perspective**.  You can/should start all cards with "As a user, I need the game to..." then follow with a particular feature,  for example  "... show my high score on the same page as the global high-scores are kept [because ... here optional reasons for why user may want this feature].
- review each story and assign a **rough estimation of the time** involved in implementing it
- review each story and assign **a priority level** (scale may vary, but something simple like "Must have from Version 1.0", "Should eventually be in there, for sure", "Would be nice to have" and "Maybe nice to have...")
- **organize *releases***, on the basis of what you can do within say 2 or 3 weeks, maximum.  If a particular feature were to take too long, schedule it for a later release.
- **implement** the features assigned to the current release
- **iterate** through this release cycle, **reviewing the requirements** as you go, for the relative importance of features, and also the need of new features may become evident as with the insight provided by using the [incomplete/imperfect] intermediate releases.

Answer (score 1):

Books like the one you describe are focused at a different audience, but there is value in the general concepts presented. Fully developed requirements documents are not as common as you might think. Don't let anyone think that you are a 'bad developer' for not having the most detailed requirements.

Requirements docs might be more important if you need to communicate the requirements with a co-developer.

If you are the sole developer I would strongly recommend that you spend your efforts on the design and implementation of the game, over requirements. If you have a good idea of what you build then let this flow as you build it.

Documentation can help you. The question is what is going to be most beneficial. Maybe design decisions are more critical than requirements for you but not for others. You'll maybe want to have a list of things that people have requested or ideas that you think of but cannot implement straight away. Sometimes a whiteboard can be handy for sketching out things, it's not just a tool for collaboration with other people.

Comment: There is no schedule constraints in this project.  My main goal is quality.  I would like to write requirements and then do design to build strong habits, as at work we usually have very small projects that we jump right into construction with.

Comment: I can see where you are coming from, but requirements, design documents et al. will in no way guarantee that you end up with a quality product. You need to find a games community and make some observations on the behaviours of the leading developers.

Answer (score 1):

Here's just a general approach...

1. Solidify the concept...write it in plain English first (ex: The game is a first person shooter.  You kill zombies and hunt for treasure.)
2. Get a paper pad and pencil and draw out the general flow of the game and the main screens the users will encounter...main menu, options screen, help, etc.  Make sure it makes sense.
3. Go to a site like [mockingbird](http://gomockingbird.com/) and create the detail wireframes for your screens...
4. Print these out and do some paper prototyping...i.e. put the printout in front of you and 'click' on a button...then bring up the appropriate screen...then click on another button, etc.
5. Once that makes sense, you can try to start coding your game.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I believe you should use your own way to do this. The most commonly available one's will not match with your requirement. They might be suitable for a common commercial server application but not for a game. And since iPhone gaming is a new trend you may have to look in a different perspective.. You may not be able to fill a document with standard requirements and you may have different set of New type of requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion...  Sign up with Google Sites, and create a private site with documentation of the game, requirements, technical aspects, work log, etc...  You can share it with select people, and it always keeps edit history.

I like it better than a Wiki because it is more structured, and just plain simple to use.